# Why is declaredFields including $change and serialVersionUID

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

In my android project I'm trying to loop through all the fields of a class using reflection, however, the result of `declaredFields` includes two unexpected fields, `$change` and `serialVersionUID` which aren't defined in the class

This is in an android project using a Kotlin data class. I've tried looking up the two fields in question and have seen that `serialVersionUID` seems to relate to classes which extend serialisable (https://stackoverflow.com/a/285809/8023278), the class in question doesn't implement `serialisable` though and I can't find any details about `$change`.

```
data class MyClass(
        @field:Json(name = "Id") var id: String
)

// then in some other class/method
MyClass::class.java.declaredFields.forEach { 
  // do something. 
  Log.d("", it.name)
}
```

I would expect only id to be logged however I actually get id, `$change` and `serialVersionUID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone that encounters this in the future.

The extra fields seem to be added by [instant run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run), disabling instant run fixed the problem. I have instant run disabled on my machine and wasn't seeing the two extra fields however my colleagues had instant run enabled and were all getting both `$change` and `serialVersionUID`.

Another solution I found was to filter out these fields. `$change` appears to be synthetic so can check against [`isSynthetic()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#isSynthetic()).
What I ended up actually doing was checking if the kotlin property of the field was null which it is for these two fields and not the classes actual fields.

```
MyClass::class.java.declaredFields.filter { it.kotlinProperty != null }.forEach {
 // ...
}
```